# How to get values of multiple textboxes from a php loop and sum them using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

What i want is that every row should have its summation (row1=price x quantity) as the quantity changes the sum should be changing automatically(total=row1 + row2 +row3) so as the total of all rows.As it is am only able to achieve that with first row. Test my code here  https://malawiclinic.000webhostapp.com/

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <?php
        $sqlm="SELECT * FROM tbl_wishlist ORDER BY id DESC ";
        $resultmn=mysqli_query($db,$sqlm);
        $fcount=mysqli_num_rows($resultmn);

        if ($fcount>0) {
            $countprice=0;
            while($found = mysqli_fetch_array($resultmn)) {
                $product = $found['product'];
                $qty = $found['Quantity'];
                $price = $found['price'];
                echo "
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <label for='exampleInputName2'>$product</label>
                        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='price'
                               value='$price'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <input type='number' class='input-text form-control'
                               id='quantity' value='$qty'>
                    </div>
                    <label for='exampleInputName2'>$
                        <span id='result'></span>
                    </label>";
            }
        } ?>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).on("input",".input-text", function(){
            var x = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
            var x1 = document.getElementById("price").value;
            var total = x1 * x;
            var totals = total.toLocaleString(undefined,
                                              {maximumFractionDigits:2});
            $("#result").html(totals);
            $("#totals").html(totals);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You are using the same `id`s for multiple elements. `id`s are supposed to be unique. Try to use `class`es instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `id` attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document). You have three fields with `id="price"`, three with `id="quantity"` and three with `id="result"` which is not valid, so you should remove those `id`(s).

Now, you will have to access these fields using their class names by `getElementsByClassName`. Since, all the fields have `form-control` as their common class, this code below will do the job. And also replace all `id="result"` with `class="result"`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var input = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control');
  var result = document.getElementsByClassName('result');
  var total = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<input.length; i+=2){
    var product = input[i].value * input[i+1].value;
    total += product;
    product = product.toLocaleString(undefined, {maximumFractionDigits:2});
    result[i/2].innerHTML = product;
  }
  total = total.toLocaleString(undefined, {maximumFractionDigits:2});
  $("#totals").html(total);
});
```

Comment: The `id` "result" exists multiple times too. Your code won't do the job for the result/subtotals.

Comment: @VermaJr. its working  in the way that it is giving me the sum of all products but i also would like to have total of every row displaying  to the right of the row is it possible?